# Integer does not want to initialise

Tags: vhdl

```
architecture RTL of design is

    signal input : integer range 0 to 16777216 := 0 ; 
     ....

begin

    -- VHDL entity instantiations 
    -- named association, instead of positional

    input_stage: ENTITY work.input_stage

        port map(
            ... 
            input => input

        );

    filter: ENTITY work.filter 

        port map (
            input => input,
--          ... 

        );                          

end architecture RTL;
```

The error: value -2147483648 for input is out of range 0 to 16777216.

So it looks like I can't override the default value. Is that possible?

Comment: 16777216 is an odd top of range to choose for an unsigned integer, as you need 25 bits, 16777215 would make more sense and fully use 24 bits. -2147483648 is maximum negative scale for a 32 bit signed integer. Are you sure you've thought through what numbers you want represented and how?

Comment: @Neil_UK I want to process 24 bit audio, so yes 16777215 would make more sense. Still doesn't explain why it doesn't properly initialise ...

Comment: Can you show your test bench and what software you use? Unlike variables, signals are only updated on the next Signal Update Phase of the current simulation cycle; your error looks like the signal doesn't get updated before you use it.

Comment: Without component declarations showing port modes your readers might imagine either filter or input_stage drives the signal input (both have input as the actual for port input). More likely is that which ever one drives input isn't constraining the value it's assigning. Show the port declarations, drivers for input including any assignment statements and any declarations for objects involved in the right hand side of those assignments. What would be called on Stackoverflow a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.

Comment: @Maarten also, you shouldn't initialize signals.

Comment: @DonFusili why not? I understand that it is not synthesizable but I only intended to use it for simulation.

Comment: @Maarten Because it doesn't make sense. If you reset the signal asynchronously as well, you're inducing delta cycles for nothing. You're describing hardware, which doesn't have a starting point. I guess it will work in your case and I'm just nitpicking, but not mentioning it would leave a bad taste in my mouth.

Comment: @DonFusili Xilinx (and possibly others) do in fact set the registers to the initial value during the GSR (Global Set/Reset) and I believe it is actually (Xilinx) recommended practice for signals that need to be initialized only at power on (vs using reset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer in range shouldn't be added in the top level entity but in the entity that is driving the signal, in my case input_stage.

```
entity input_stage is
    generic(
        ...
    );
    port(
        ...
        input              : out integer range 0 to 16777215;

    );
end entity input_stage;
```